# How can I collect a vector of Traits from an iterator of structs implementing that trait

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

I'm trying to get a vector of traits from an iterator of structs implementing that trait.

So far I was able to do this :

```rust
    fn foo() -> Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>> {
        let v: Vec<_> = vec![1]
            .iter()
            .map(|i| {
                let b: Box<dyn SomeTrait> = Box::new(TraitImpl { id: *i });
                b
            })
            .collect();
        v
    }
```

But I would like to make it more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd69c58af89b268a1e0ed413efcd6a00)

Though I'm not a Rust guru, so I'm not sure about `'static` limitation in `foo<S: SomeTrait + 'static>`

```
trait SomeTrait { fn echo(&self); }
impl SomeTrait for u32 {
    fn echo(&self) {
        println!("{}", self);
    }
}

fn foo<S: SomeTrait + 'static>(iter: impl Iterator<Item=S>) -> Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>> {
    iter.map(|e| Box::new(e) as Box<dyn SomeTrait>).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!(1_u32, 2, 3);
    let sv = foo(v.into_iter());
    sv.iter().for_each(|e| e.echo());
}
```